# How can I loop through text, reading data from a file into several variables in c?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I realize this sounds like a duplicate question, and it probably is, but I've been looking for a few days. My messed up code is this:

```
node* deSerialize(FILE *fp) {
    char key[20];
    char value[MAXSIZE];
    node *n = NULL;
    while (fscanf(fp, " %[^*]*%[^*]* ",key,value)==2) {
        if (n) {
            n = add_node(n,key,value);
        }
        else{
            n = new_node(key,value);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

But when I save the deserialized structure back to a disk, it only saves the last key/value. Like this:

`test*value* test*value* test*value* test*value* test*value* test*value* test*value* test*value*`

Whereas the serialized struct looked like this:

`key1*value1* key2*value2* key3*value3* key4*value4* key5*value5* key6*value6* key7*value7* test*value*`

I understand that the string pointers (or array pointers, not sure what to call it really) `key` and `value` are getting updated and hence they all point to the same thing in the end, but how can I prevent that?

For completeness, here are the other involved functions:

```
void serialize(FILE *fp, node *n) {
    node *j = n;
    while (j) {
        while(j->left) {
            serialize(fp,j->left);
            j->left=NULL;
        }
        while(j->right) {
            serialize(fp,j->right);
            j->right=NULL;
        }

        fprintf(fp,"%s*%s* ",j->key,j->value);
        j=NULL;
    }
}

node* new_node(char *key, char *value) {
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(struct node));
    result->key = key;
    result->hash = hash(key);
    result->value = value;
    result->left = result->right = NULL;
    return result;
}

node* add_node(node* tree, char *key, char *value ) {
    unsigned long h = hash(key);
    if (tree==NULL)
        tree=new_node(key,value);
    if (h<tree->hash)
        tree->left = add_node(tree->left,key,value);
    if (h>tree->hash)
        tree->right = add_node(tree->right,key,value);
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `node`? Where is the serialization code? Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to dynamically allocate memory for a duplicate string in your structure. Currently, you overwrite the data you had previously because all nodes reference the same array.

You do **not** want to create a two-dimensional array, though, because on return from your function, your nodes will be referencing memory on the stack that has already been cleaned up. (The local array is placed on the stack, and is removed when the function returns.) The proper way to do this is to use dynamic memory allocation.

Here is a method to save your data with dynamic allocation:

```
node* new_node(char *key, char *value) {
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(struct node));

    result->key = strdup(key); //DUPLICATE STRING

    result->hash = hash(key);
    result->value = value;
    result->left = result->right = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

You don't have to know the size of the strings beforehand. Also, you'll want to `free()` the memory you have allocated by implementing a `destroy_node()` function:

```
void destroy_node(node *n) {
    if (n != NULL) {
        free(n->key);
        free(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I need to `free` a node if it gets added to a tree?

Comment: @rofls - No, you don't. You only want to destroy the nodes when you are done using them. (i.e. when you no longer need the tree) Otherwise, you are bound to get some undefined behavior somewhere by using an already `free`d pointer.

Comment: wait you and @alter_man are disagreeing :( Aaah! I haven't implemented his but it seemed more complete so I selected it. Upvoted ya both though... Thanks :)

Comment: BTW, with @alter_mans solution you are more than likely going to get a segmentation fault. Note the second paragraph in this answer. And it's better to have the data allocated by the node *owned* by the node, like in this answer.

Comment: thank you. yours is simpler. i'll test it, if it works i'll probably switch to selecting it.

Answer (score 2):

```
But when I save the deserialized structure back to a disk, it only saves the last key/value.
```

You are storing on the same variables in the loop, reserve with `malloc` on each iteration if you don't know the number of rows before-hand.

> More detail on dynamically allocating with malloc would still be
>   awesome though

Something like this (not tested):

```
   char *key;
   char *value;
   node *n = NULL;

   while (1) {
       key = malloc(20);
       if (key == NULL) {
           /* raise error */
       }
       value = malloc(MAX_SIZE);
       if (value == NULL) {
           /* raise error */
       }
       if (fscanf(fp, " %[^*]*%[^*]* ", key, value) != 2) {
           free(key);
           free(value);
           break;
       }
       if (n) {
           n = add_node(n, key, value);
       } else {
           n = new_node(key, value);
       }
   }
```

You must `free` those values (maybe in the `tree_destroy()` function) in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: This looks good thank you :) I don't know the size though, can you show me what to do to reserve space with malloc on each iteration?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I think I can implement a counter in the serialize function pretty easily.

Comment: More detail on dynamically allocating with `malloc` would still be awesome though :D

Comment: Uhmm, why would you return a node referencing the address of a local array?

Comment: @owacoder, you're right, for some reason I thought it was in `main`.